# How to calculate the weighted value to give numbers?

Tags: weighted-data

Big picture question: How do I calculate the weight to give certain categories?

Specifics: I have data for 70 counties, population in each county, and then number of sales in each county. How do I create the weighted value for each county? To give small population counties and large population counties equal amounts of weight.

Comment: Why would you want to give equal weight to counties with unequal populations?

Answer (score 1):

Divide the sales value of each country by its population. You get average sales by person, which is not elegant. To get nicer result multiply the result with a large constant (e.g. 100 000) to get standardized sales by 100 000 people.

Comment: I need to give the populations equal weights though. Dividing sales by population would give each county its weighted value, but I need to give each county the same weighted value. Basically so that smaller counties are given more weight, while larger counties are given less weight.

Comment: The above-mentioned solution provides with the values of sales as if each country has the same population. It is not your aim?

Comment: Do you mean divide the sales in each county by the total population of all counties added up?

Comment: No, divide the sales of country A by population of country A. You get the sales by average person in country A. Then do the same with country B.